# Joining two case statements

Tags: oracle, case

I would like to check is it possible to join two case statements together?  I've tried something like this, but I'm having error 'ConsumptionBill is invalid identifier'. I know I get this error as I do not have a ConsumptionBill attribute.

So is it still possible to join the two case statement?

```
    SELECT CustName, preRead, newRead, newRead-preRead AS TotConsumption, 
CASE
   WHEN SYSDATE - sentDate > 30 THEN Consumption + FP
   WHEN SYSDATE - sentDate > 45 THEN Consumption + SP
   ELSE ConsumptionBill + 0
  END as BIll
FROM ( 
        SELECT C.firstName||''||C.lastName as CustName, R.newReading prevRead,
               lead(R.newReading) OVER (PARTITION BY R.electircmeterID ORDER BY R.dateVisit) AS newRead, B.firstconRate as FR,
               B.secconRate as SR, B.thirdconRate as TR, P.firstPenAmt as FP, P.secPenAmt as SP, bl.sentDate,
               CASE
                WHEN newRead-preRead <= 20 THEN (newRead-preRead)*FR
                WHEN newRead-preRead <= 30 THEN 20*FR + (newRead-preRead-100)*SR
                WHEN newRead-preRead > 40 THEN 20*FR + 30*SR + ((newRead-previousRead)-50)*TR 
              END as Consumption
        FROM reading R, svcaddress S, electricmeter W, customer C, rate A, nonresrate B, penRate P, bill bl
           WHERE W.electricmeterID = S.electricmeterID 
           AND R.electricmeterID = W.electricmeterID 
           AND A.rateID = S.rateID
           AND B.rateID = A.rateID
           AND C.customerID = S.customerID 
           AND C.customerID = bl.customerID 
           AND R.readingID = bl.readingID
           AND P.preRateID = C.preRateID
           AND C.customerType = 'NonResidential'
           AND  r.datevisited >=  TO_DATE('01-05-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') 
           AND r.datevisited < TO_DATE('31-08-2013','DD-MM-YYYY')
        )where newRead is not null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing it in context of what you are doing.

However, you probably want a subselect

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN SYSDATE - sentDate > 30 THEN ConsumptionBill + FP;
   WHEN SYSDATE - sentDate > 45 THEN ConsumptionBill + SP
   ELSE ConsumptionBill + 0
  END as TotalBIll
FROM (
  SELECT FP,
    sentDate,
    SP,
    CASE
      WHEN newRead-previousRead <= 100 THEN (newRead-previousRead)*FR
      WHEN newRead-previousRead <= 200 THEN 100*FR + (newRead-previousRead-100)*SR
      WHEN newRead-previousRead > 200 THEN 100*FR + 100*SR + ((newRead-previousRead)-200)*TR 
    END as ConsumptionBill
  FROM my_table
) t
```

Here, we create an intermediate record set `t` that included that calculated field `ConsumptionBill` we want to use later on.

(I say "intermediate", but only conceptually...the query planner may or may not make an intermediate record set -- it probably won't.)

Comment: I think this is probably what the OP wants. CASE/WHEN can be used in PL/SQL but since he has used aliases, I am betting it is SQL that he wants.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, I've already edited the question to show my full query. like what toddlermenot has said I'm actually using SQL. 
So does the sub query still works?

Comment: @user3856751, yes, though it appears that you can move the `ConsumptionBill` portion into your existing subquery without creating any new ones.

Comment: @PaulDraper I've already tried to put the `ConsumptionBill` into my existing sub query. but it seems that it always returns a `invalid identifier` for my second case statement.
i've already updated the query in my question as well.